# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'width')

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, phaserjs

I am trying to make my own world editor in Javascript. I am using a folder of individual tiles and placing them on screen. Then when you press on the tile you basically choose it. That works, but when the pointerdown switches from tile picking to tile placing I get this error.

I have checked if everything is defined but I might be missing something

Update: I have changed the arrow functions to use normal ones but it still doesnt work and gives the same error and am now providing the whole file code

**i have encountered this**
console.log(this.map)
VM10362:1 undefined
undefined

[These are the errors aka stack trace i think](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XS9r6.png)

this is my code

```
class WorldEditor extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor() {
        super("editWorld")
        this.tileSize = 48
        this.tileIndex = 0
        this.tileFolder = 'Assets/Tiles/'
        this.tilesPerRow = 37
        this.totalTiles = 160
        this.tilePicked = false
    }

    preload() {
        // Load tile images from the folder
        for (let i = 0; i < this.totalTiles; i++) {
            this.load.image('tile (' + i + ')', this.tileFolder + 'tile (' + i + ').png')
        }
    }

    create() {
        const tileWidth = this.tileSize
        const tileHeight = this.tileSize
        const tilesPerRow = this.tilesPerRow
    
        if(!this.map){
            this.map = this.make.tilemap({ 
                tileWidth: this.tileSize, 
                tileHeight: this.tileSize,
                width: 1200,
                height: 720
            })  
        }
        
        for (let i = 0; i < this.totalTiles; i++) {
            const x = ((i % tilesPerRow) * tileWidth)/1.48
            const y = (Math.floor(i / tilesPerRow) * tileHeight)/1.48
    
            this.tile = this.add.image(x, y, 'tile (' + i + ')')
            this.tile.setOrigin(0)
            this.tile.setScale((tileWidth / this.tile.width)/1.48, (tileHeight / this.tile.height)/1.48)
        }
    
        // Set up pointer events
        this.setupPointerEvents()
        
        // Keyboard event to switch back to tile selection
        this.input.keyboard.on('keydown-F', () => {
            this.tilePicked = false
            console.log('Switched back to tile selection')
            this.setupPointerEvents() // Update pointer events after switching back
        })
    }
    
    setupPointerEvents() {
        this.input.off('pointerdown')
    
        if (!this.tilePicked) {
            const tiles = this.children.list.filter(child => child.texture && child.texture.key.startsWith('tile ('))
            tiles.forEach((tile, i) => {
                tile.setInteractive()
                tile.on('pointerdown', function() {
                    this.tileIndex = i
                    this.tilePicked = true
                    tile.setTint(0xff0000)
                    console.log('Selected tile index:', this.tileIndex)
                    this.setupPointerEvents()
                }, this)
            })
        } else {
            this.input.on('pointerdown', function(pointer) {
                this.tileX = Math.floor(pointer.x / this.tileSize)
                this.tileY = Math.floor(pointer.y / this.tileSize)
                this.placeTile(this.tileX, this.tileY)
            }, this)
        }
    }
    // Other methods...
    
    placeTile(tileX, tileY) {
        this.map.putTileAt(this.tileIndex, tileX, tileY) 
    }

    // Implement saveMap and loadMap functions to save and load level data
}
```

Comment: Well, that error obviously refers to either `config` or `tile`. Have you set breakpoints to check their values during operation?

Comment: Where is the variable `config` supposed to get a value?

Comment: The error message should also give you the line number, if you supply this, that will help.  Browsers debuggers these days are 1st class, and clicking on the callstack will even take you to the code that caused the error.

Comment: The config is in game.js
and the line problems are  
this.map.putTileAt(this.tileIndex, tileX, tileY) and this.placeTile(tileX, tileY)
the rest of the errors are all located in phaser.js

Comment: There's no reference in your original code to the "line problems" section you just added. What are "the rest of the errors"?

Comment: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'width')
    at t.exports (phaser.min.js:1:1082810)
    at t.exports [as PutTileAt] (phaser.min.js:1:1084458)
    at initialize.putTileAt (phaser.min.js:1:1057178)
    at WorldEditor.placeTile (WorldEditor.js:79:18)
    at initialize.<anonymous> (WorldEditor.js:72:22)
    at a.emit (phaser.min.js:1:1600)
    at initialize.processDownEvents (phaser.min.js:1:471023)
    at initialize.update (phaser.min.js:1:468865)
    at initialize.updateInputPlugins (phaser.min.js:1:461466)
    at initialize.onMouseDown (phaser.min.js:1:462898)

Comment: And the phaser lines are all from the phaser library
should i also provide the lines from phaser that cause the errors?

Comment: Okay, that's not additional errors, but the stacktrace that shows where each call is being initiated. Sounds like you are passing in a variable to a function that doesn't have all the properties it requires.

Comment: You should edit the error and stack trace into your question. As comments, that sort of content is unreadable.

Comment: Yes I am sorry im new to this and trying haha

Comment: I tried to put values in the map width and height instead of the config and it did nothing.
the same issue persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a tileset image i dont use and a layer and now it works
thank you for all of the help!

```
if(!this.map){
            this.map = this.make.tilemap({ 
                tileWidth: this.tileSize, 
                tileHeight: this.tileSize,
                width: 1200,
                height: 720
            })  

            const tileset = this.map.addTilesetImage('tiles', 'tiles', this.tileSize, this.tileSize)
            const groundLayer = this.map.createBlankLayer('groundLayer', tileset)
        }
```

Comment: Good short answer/solution. If possible please accept your own answer _(with the greencheckmark under the voting arrows)_, so that the question appears resolved. This help other people with the same issue find a solution faster.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that there is no layer created. create a layer (with a tileset) and there should be no errors.

> **btw.:** the arrow functions and the `this` scopes are in this specific case *(phaser development)* correct.

**Mini Example that solves the issue:**
*(I might update it to make it look better)*
Just click the white square. and check the Browser console

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';
console.clear();

class MainScene extends Phaser.Scene{
    create () {
        this.add.text(10,10, 'DEMO TEXT')
        const tileHeight = 10
        const tilesPerRow = 3
        
        // just for the demo -- START
        let graphics  = this.make.graphics();
        graphics.fillStyle(0xffffff);
        graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
        graphics.generateTexture('tileset', 100, 100);
        // just for the demo -- END        
        
        if(!this.map){
            this.map = this.make.tilemap({ 
                tileWidth: tileHeight, 
                tileHeight: tileHeight,
                width: config.width,
                height: config.height
            })  
            
            const tileset = this.map.addTilesetImage('tileset', null, 10, 10);
            this.layer = this.map.createBlankLayer('layer1', tileset);
        }
        
        for (let i = 0; i < 9 ; i++) {
            const x = ((i % tilesPerRow) * tileHeight)
            const y = (Math.floor(i / tilesPerRow) * tileHeight)
    
            // just for the demo
            graphics.generateTexture('tile (' + i + ')', 10, 10);
            
            this.tile = this.add.image(x, y, 'tile (' + i + ')')
            this.tile.setOrigin(0)
            this.tile.setScale(10, 10)
        }
    
        // Set up pointer events
        this.setupPointerEvents()
        
        // Keyboard event to switch back to tile selection
        this.input.keyboard.on('keydown-F', () => {
            this.tilePicked = false
            console.log('Switched back to tile selection')
            this.setupPointerEvents() // Update pointer events after switching back
        })
   
    }
    
     setupPointerEvents() {
        this.input.off('pointerdown')
    
        if (!this.tilePicked) {
            const tiles = this.children.list.filter(child => child.texture && child.texture.key && (/tile \(/).test(child.texture.key))
            tiles.forEach((tile, i) => {
                tile.setInteractive()
                tile.on('pointerdown', () => {
                    this.tileIndex = i
                    this.tilePicked = true
                    tile.setTint(0xff0000)
                    console.log('Selected tile index:', this.tileIndex)
                    this.setupPointerEvents()
                })
            })
        } else {
            this.input.on('pointerdown', (pointer) => {
                const tileX = Math.floor(pointer.x / 10)
                const tileY = Math.floor(pointer.y / 10)
                this.placeTile(tileX, tileY)
            })
        }
    }
    
    placeTile(tileX, tileY) {
        console.info('tileplaced')
        this.map.putTileAt(this.tileIndex, tileX, tileY, this.layer) 
    }
}

var config = {
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    scene: MainScene
}; 



new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes thank you...
such a weird error but thank you
I fixed it